# Install openldap server wth puppet - Error: Could not prefetch openldap_database provider 'olc': Command original_slapcat is missing

Tags: puppet, openldap, puppet-agent

i am trying to install openldap server with Puppet Version  5.5.20. For the openldap installation  i use camptocamp/openldap module v 2.0.0. I try it first with minimal configuration. My puppet manifest file is

```
# Test installation OpenLDAP 
class srv::testldap (
) {

  class { 'openldap::server': }
  openldap::server::database { 'dc=example,dc=com':
  ensure => present,
}


}
```

An error comes by running puppet agent:

```
"Error: Could not prefetch openldap_database provider 'olc': Command original_slapcat is missing"
```

I would be very appreciative of any help.

Comment: Is `slapd` present on the VM? Its complaining it can't find it in it's path: https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-openldap/blob/3afd84f74958ea380f717c6b102d0f9f787911e2/lib/puppet/provider/openldap.rb#L7

Comment: but with this class declaration  `class { 'openldap::server': }` slapd should be installed automatically on the VM ?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this error if I do a `puppet agent apply --test --noop`: camptocamp/openldap requires ldap utilities to be installed introspect the server state.

When the `--noop` is removed the command succeeds.